# how to create data fields in xml for windows8 (c#-xaml) metro app ? how to access and parse that data ? and how to import that xml data in xaml UI?

Tags: c#, xaml, xml-parsing, microsoft-metro, xsd

I'am programming a Windows 8 Store App (Metro Design) with C# and XAML using Visual Studio 2012. 
 There is no need for a database server with multi user support etc.my application is like reminder and contact notes application which have to remember date and time,  I want to store my data in a local database and don't know which database is suitable for my needs. Maybe xml? Or are there solutions!
if i go for using xml then ,
how can i create data fields in xml ?
how can i import xml data in c# xaml UI ?
can someone please explain me with example ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite or XML for storing data, just Google it you will find a lot of tutorials

SQLite

[Using SQLite in a Windows Store App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-SQLite-in-a-Windows-c16aea77)

[Sqlite For Windows 8 Metro/Winrt Apps](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sqlite-For-Windows-8-Metro-2ec7a882)

[Using SQLite and sqlite-net in a Windows Store App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-SQLite-and-sqlite-79efa172)

[Tim Heuer Blog : Tagged - sqlite](http://timheuer.com/blog/Tags/sqlite/default.aspx)

[qmatteoq.com : Tagged - SQLite](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/tag/sqlite/)

XML

[Using the Documents Library as a database in Windows 8 Store apps](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/05/12/Using-the-Documents-Library-as-a-database-in-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx)

[Example Metro app /WinRT: Serializing and deseralizing objects using XMLSerializer to StorageFile and LocalFolder using generics and async/await threading](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/11/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-using-xmlserializer-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/)

Comment: Thank you so much ! i was searching for it ... :)